# SQL:batchcompleted has a long duration.

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-profiler

I have a problem with a program I am running, where a query sometimes take 10-30 seconds to complete.
I thought about using the SQL profiler to help me identify the problem.

The profiler definately shows that there is a problem, but I dont really know what to do about it. 
The following image is from the profiler:
[image: profiler]

Can somebody tell me something about that query?

The thing is that IUModule.TaskSchedulerChangeMessages is not a scheme that exists so i'm wondering how this query can even be run.

Comment: That duration is just the 60 second timeout for your service broker `waitfor` statement. Presumably no messages were received in that minute.

Comment: I need a bit more elaboration on that. Are you saying that the duration doesn't actually affect the database?

Comment: Yes. It's just waiting for a message. And not consuming any resources from the 0 CPU and 4 reads.

Comment: And it does not block for other queries while waiting?

Comment: Wouldn't have thought so unless it is in a transaction with something else that holds a lock. You need to look at the waiting tasks DMVs if you suspect blocking. Likely the issue is nothing to do with that statement though.

Comment: All right. It's just the "Waitfor" statement in the beginning of the line that made me worry that it would block.

Comment: Is there a place where I can see where the service brokers queries come from? because thatparticular query should definately not be run since the scheme doesn't exist.